# How can I share a link to one of my answers, without accessing from my profile?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

When I click on an one of my answers from my profile, I get a direct link location of my answer from that post. When I want to share one of my answers I have to swim through my answers to try and find the page. The alternative I've used it to just keep the question as a favorite so its easier to access. But doing this is not a direct link to my answer, but just the question page. Is there an easier way to share an answer without having to scan though pages of answers?

Comment: Perhaps boost your [search foo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching). You can include `user:me is:answer` in your search query and add some keywords that would help improve the search to find the unique answer you're after...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every answer has a "share" link below it, right beside the "edit" and "flag" links. Click that, and you'll get a popup presenting you with a URL directly to the answer in question. Try it on this one!

If you're logged in, the share link will be in the form:

```
http://somesite.stackexchange.com/a/(some number)/(another number)
```

The first number is the answer ID. The second number will be your user ID, and it's there for the [Announcer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/74/announcer) / [Booster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/75/booster) / [Publicist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/publicist) badges.

The share link is right here.
↓

Comment: [Test](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210727/233028)